# How to get my GET value?

Tags: javascript, get

When I go to this link : `http://main.php?valretour=OK`, how can I get the value of `valretour`?

Main.php

I tried this directly in my PHP page...:

```
<script>
    alert($_GET['valretour']);
    if($_GET['valretour'] == "OK"){
        $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Success', message : 'OK' });
    } else {
        $.toaster({ priority : 'warning', title : 'Failed', message : 'NOT' });
    }
</script>
```

My page `main.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Links css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.toaster.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logost.png" style="width:180px;height:120px"></a>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
            alert($_GET['valretour']);
                if($_GET['valretour'] == "OK"){
                    $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Success', message : 'OK' });
                } else {
                    $.toaster({ priority : 'warning', title : 'Failed', message : 'NOT' });
                }
            alert();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse `location.search`:

```
var query = (function() {
    function decode(string) {
        return decodeURIComponent(string.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var result = {};
    if (location.search) {
        location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach(function(pair) {
            pair = pair.split('=');
            result[decode(pair[0])] = decode(pair[1]);
        });
    }
    return result;
})();


if(query['valretour'] == "OK"){
    $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Success', message : 'OK' });
} else {
    $.toaster({ priority : 'warning', title : 'Failed', message : 'NOT' });
}
```

Comment: @PierreBelin I've removed jquery reference.

Comment: how can I put it back ?

Comment: @PierreBelin what jQuery?

Comment: @PierreBelin you should ask another question with toaster code.

Comment: But I have others toaster in my JS and it works on others page, but here it doesn't... Maybe it's because you removed jquery reference ?

Comment: @PierreBelin no, it shouldn't matter. I've only changed $.each by forEach.

Comment: I know, I messed up. I was because my javascript call order was wrong. I called toaster before jquery... Thanks you anyway ! Really